analyse motor signals
I am currently working on university project where we have reference motor sounds (from different cars) and we have test sounds of motors(need to refer test signals to one of the reference). And I already tried different things,such as normalizing signals, filtering it with bypass filter, fft and cross corellation after that. And I still getting weird results (all test signals are referred to one reference, but this situation isn’t possible). Maybe you can help me with how can I solve this problem or share your ideas with me about how to deal with this project. Thank you in advance

It's best to know what your signal looks or sounds like.
Without knowing the exact form of your signal, I think there are three things you could try:
(1) Regardless of the principle, classification or inter-correlation algorithms have to satisfy an important property: a signal is always closest to itself.
You can test your algorithm by this property. For example, if you have reference signals A,B and C, you can use your algorithm to compute their correlation with each other to get a 3 by 3 correlation matrix. The elements on the diagonal of this matrix must be 1, indicating that a signal is identical to itself, while the other elements must be less than 1, surfacing a difference between two different signals.
If that doesn't turn out to be the case, you know there must be something wrong with your correlation algorithm.
(2) The human brain is a very powerful classifier. Take your data and put it into a format that can be listened to or looked at, and then try to do what your algorithm is supposed to do. If you can easily distinguish which reference signal the test signal belongs to, then a less complex algorithm should be able to do the same thing; if you also have a hard time making the classification accurately, then you don't want this algorithm to be too simple.
On the other hand, if you make the same judgment as your algorithm (all test signals are referred to one reference), that would indicate that there is nothing wrong with your algorithm, and that the dataset itself may be faulty.
(3) Use filters. It is possible that all test signals point to the same reference because they have the same extraneous signal. Examine the spectrum of the signals to find the part that really makes a difference and filter out the rest with a bandpass filter. This will increase the signal-to-noise ratio and may solve your problem.

Thank you very much, I will try this. I already tried to filter my signals with a low pass filter, but I will try to use band-pass filter. I also tried to distinguish signals by listening to the audio, but I am not sure…

one more problem is that, in addition, the sounds can be different (in the sense of different noise levels), and also the sounds of the engines of the same cars are always at different speeds, so even when we use cross-correlation, we do not get an exact answer, because the signals can be similar in structure, but different in periodicity.Maybe you have some advice how to deal with this problem?

If you can't hear the difference between the sounds either, then the question is no less difficult.

As for problems due to frequency changes, they are relatively easy to fix. Using proven algorithms, you can lock the fundamental frequency of the sound. After locking the fundamental frequency you can directly compare the scaled waveforms, or you can use the Fourier Transform to compare the intensity and phase of the harmonic components.

What are your objectives? Compare a new sound with a reference sound? What would be the purpose of such comparison?
